# Sorting a Max Heap returns a sorted list in decending order. Should be in ascending order?

Tags: java, sorting, heapsort, max-heap

My professor gave us a walk through on creating a Max Heap class using an ArrayList. He then tasked us with writing a maxHeapSort method. I've almost been successful in sorting the heap in descending order, but I was under the assumption a sort should be in ascending order. Right now I'm using an ArrayList with max heap [11, 5, 8, 3, 4, 1] which is sorting to [11, 8, 5, 3, 4, 1].

Here is my maxHeapSort code:

```
protected void maxHeapSort() {
    int n = this.heap.size();

    if(this.heap.size() == 0){
        return;
    }

    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i --){
        T temp = this.heap.get(0);
        this.heap.set(0, this.heap.get(i));
        this.heap.set(i, temp);

        this.heapifyDown(0);
    }
}
```

here is the heapifyDown method given by my professor:

```
protected void heapifyDown(int index){
    // get the left and right children indices
    int leftIndex = 2 * index + 1;
    int rightIndex = 2 * index + 2;

    // set the max to the one that we are trying to heapify
    int maxIndex = index;

    // figure out which value is the max
    if(leftIndex < this.size && this.heap.get(leftIndex).compareTo(this.heap.get(maxIndex)) > 0){
        maxIndex = leftIndex;
    }

    if(rightIndex < this.size && this.heap.get(rightIndex).compareTo(this.heap.get(maxIndex)) > 0){
        maxIndex = rightIndex;
    }

    // do we need to swap and keep heapifying
    if (maxIndex != index) {
        // swap
        T temp = this.heap.get(index);
        this.heap.set(index, this.heap.get(maxIndex));
        this.heap.set(maxIndex, temp);

        // recurse
        this.heapifyDown(maxIndex);
    }

}
```

And here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void testMaxHeapSort(){
    MaxHeap<Integer> maxHeap = new MaxHeap<>();
    maxHeap.heap.add(11);
    maxHeap.heap.add(5);
    maxHeap.heap.add(8);
    maxHeap.heap.add(3);
    maxHeap.heap.add(4);
    maxHeap.heap.add(1);

    maxHeap.size = 6;

    maxHeap.maxHeapSort();

    assertEquals("[1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11]", maxHeap.heap.toString());
}
```

Comment: A *max* heap should be internally ordered largest element first.  It shouldn't actually be sorted, though.

Comment: I didn't look closely at your code, but the comments about "sorting" do not sound right. To be a max heap, any node N has to be smaller than its parent P, so the biggest value goes to the very top of the entire data structure. It says nothing about how other values relate to each other (like you would need if you were trying to sort the data).

Comment: I'm aware of what the max heap is, as you say it has the largest element first. However, the instruction was to create a method to sort the Max Heap

Comment: Ok, so you're implementing [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)? Can you post your code for `maxHeap.maxHeapSort();`?

Comment: @Kaan unfortunately the heapifyDown method was the code provided by the professor. I didn't write any of it. In theory, it is ment to be used to create a max heap after data is inserted into an array. It specifically targets the object at an index which is not in the correct position for a heap. It's very confusing, which is why I'm having difficulty with the sort method.

Comment: @Kaan the first block of code in the OP is the code for maxHeapSort(), the last block is the creation of a heap, followed by the execution of the  method, followed by the assertion with the expected outcome

Comment: Oh derp, didn't see that code. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Kaan, no problem, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

After reevaluating my code, I realized the heap wasn't sorting at all. It was just spitting the array back out. I adjusted the heapifyDown() method and the maxHeapSort() methods and was able to get them to work properly.

This is the code for heapifyDown():

```
protected void heapifyDown(int index, int end){
    // get the left and right children indices
    int leftIndex = 2 * index + 1;
    int rightIndex = 2 * index + 2;

    // set the max to the one that we are trying to heapify
    int maxIndex = index;

    // figure out which value is the max
    if(leftIndex < end && this.heap.get(leftIndex).compareTo(this.heap.get(maxIndex)) > 0){
        maxIndex = leftIndex;
    }

    if(rightIndex < end && this.heap.get(rightIndex).compareTo(this.heap.get(maxIndex)) > 0){
        maxIndex = rightIndex;
    }

    // do we need to swap and keep heapifying
    if (maxIndex != index) {
        // swap
        T temp = this.heap.get(index);
        this.heap.set(index, this.heap.get(maxIndex));
        this.heap.set(maxIndex, temp);

        // recurse
        this.heapifyDown(maxIndex, end);
```

Here is the code for maxHeapSort():

```
protected void maxHeapSort() {
    int n = this.heap.size();

    if(this.heap.size() == 0){
        return;
    }

    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i --){
        T temp = this.heap.get(0);
        this.heap.set(0, this.heap.get(i));
        this.heap.set(i, temp);

        this.heapifyDown(0, i);
    }
}
```

And here is the test case I used:

```
@Test
public void testMaxHeapSort(){
    MaxHeap<Integer> maxHeap = new MaxHeap<>();
    maxHeap.heap.add(11);
    maxHeap.heap.add(5);
    maxHeap.heap.add(8);
    maxHeap.heap.add(3);
    maxHeap.heap.add(4);
    maxHeap.heap.add(1);

    maxHeap.maxHeapSort();

    assertEquals("[1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11]", maxHeap.heap.toString());
}
```

The max heap [11, 5, 8, 3, 4, 1] now sorts to [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11].